# Is this additional check for parsing a string to LocalDate object necessary?

Tags: java, exception, localdate, isodate, defensive-programming

I was writing some tests for some legacy code that validates a user's date of birth. I encounter the following method in the class. My doubt is that whether the if statement in the try block is necessary. From my understanding, if the parse function returns a LocalDate object successfully, then date.toString() should always equal to the input dobstr, and there's no need to do an additional check. Am I missing anything? I could not think of any case that we need this extra check. Please help. Thanks!

```
private LocalDate format(String dobStr) throws Exception {
        LocalDate date = null;
        try {
            date = LocalDate.parse(dobStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
            if (!dobStr.equals(date.toString())) {
                 throw new DateTimeParseException("some message");
            }
        }
        catch (DateTimeParseException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return date;
}
```

---

this is what I found in the source code for DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE

```
public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_DATE;
static {
    ISO_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffsetId()
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only reason that I could see for doing a `toString()` check would be to avoid lenient issue: the parser may be lenient and try to interpret wrong values (for example: 2020-12-32 could be interpreted as 2021-01-01).

- [DateFormat allows the parser to be lenient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean))
- [The same behaviour is offered by DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-) and the default value is `ResolverStyle.SMART`.

If you want to remove it, you should check if `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` is `ResolverStyle.STRICT` by default or not. Assuming it is not STRICT by default, your code could be:

```
private LocalDate format(String dobStr) throws Exception {
  return LocalDate.parse(dobStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT));
}
```

Comment: Hi I edited the question. From the source code, I believe its default value is set to ResolverStyle.STRICT. I think it should be safe to remove that check.

Answer (score 2):

### TL;DR: The check makes a difference

If the string contains an unwanted offset ID, you will still be able to parse it using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`. But since a `LocalDate` cannot have an offset (this is what *local* in the name means), the result of `toString()` will never have that offset ID, so the strings will not be equal.

`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE` accepts an optional offset ID after the date. So if you are parsing `2020-08-12z` or `2020-08-12+01:02:03`, the custom exception would be thrown. Except for a detail: `DateTimeParseException` hasn’t got a constructor that matches a single string argument, so the code doesn’t compile. I reckon that this comes from sloppy copy-paste from the original code.

To demonstrate:

```
    String dobStr = "2020-08-12+01:02:03";
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dobStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
    String asStringAgain = date.toString();
    System.out.format("Original string: %s; result of toString(): %s; equal? %s%n",
            dobStr, asStringAgain, dobStr.equals(asStringAgain));
```

Output is:

> Original string: 2020-08-12+01:02:03; result of toString():
> 2020-08-12; equal? false

### How to obviate the check

Unless you require a custom exception in the case of an unwanted offset, the method may be written much more simply:

```
private LocalDate format(String dobStr) throws Exception {
    return LocalDate.parse(dobStr, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
}
```

`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` does not accept any offset in the string. And it is strict just like `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`, so we know that `toString()` would create the same string again.

Furthermore you may declare the method `static`, and you may leave out `throws Exception` since `DateTimeParseException` is an unchecked exception.

### Link

[Documentation of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE)